# NotAMockException when trying to verify a static method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, powermockito

I am trying to verify that a static method is not called in a certain configuration, in a unit test.

I am thus using PowerMock (`powermock-core:2.0.4` & `powermock-module-junit4:2.0.4`) and its Mockito API (`powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.4`).

When doing

```java
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);

serviceUnderTest.methodThatShouldNotCallStaticMethod(arg1, arg2); //service not of type MyClass of course

PowerMockito.verifyStatic(MyClass.class, never());
MyClass.staticMethod(any(), any());
```

on a test method within a class annotated  with

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
```

I get the following error : `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type Class and is not a mock!`.

What did I do wrong and how to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Everything seems fine besides the any(), it's best practice to cast it to the correct non primitive type or to the correct type of primitive like anyString()...etc

Comment: Thanks for the best practice !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out to be [a Powermock bug](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/992)...

Here is [the workaround](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/992#issuecomment-551521436) for anyone who could be interested :

1. Delete line `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0` " in gradle
2. Create a `src\test\resources\org\powermock\extensions\configuration.properties` file composed of the single line `mockito.mock-maker-class=mock-maker-inline`

Comment: And if you already have file org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker under src/test/resources/mockito-extensions, remember to delete it !

Comment: What about `pom.xml` for Maven? I could not find these folder and settings you mentioned above. Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

I dont have `mockito-inline` and I have `mock-maker.inline`, my setup is `org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9` and `org.mockito:mockito-core:3.10.0`.

However I found that `PowerMockito.verifyStatic` is using `Mockito.verify` underneath and when the class is checked for `isMock` mockito uses wrong `MockMaker` and can not find the class in `mockedStatics` collection.

When I used

```
Mockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
```

instead of

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
```

it started to work just fine for me.

Comment: Anyway I would agree if someone says my answer is nto 100% OK, as I just found a case where PowerMockito.mockStatic works with PowerMockito.verifyStatic, however I can not find where is the problem. I have debug the mockito quite deeps but ... at least my solution works where I need it

Comment: When I convert `PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);` to `Mockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);`, the error goene, but this time if cannot verify the hit(s) even my code hits one time and gives "*Wanted but not invoked:*" error. It just verify times(0) even it is 1 actually. Any idea?